# Blinking border, time interval, using setTimeout(), JavaScript

Tags: javascript, settimeout

i want to use setTimeout function to make border blinking, just i can't find perfect values of time to make it blink in same interval of time.
I get one long blink and one very short, again long and short. How i can get rid of short one?

Here is code:

```
function border_color(){
     document.getElementById("filedrag").style.borderColor = "white";
     setTimeout(border_color, 1500);
}

function border_color2(){
     document.getElementById("filedrag").style.borderColor = "black";
     setTimeout(border_color2, 1000);
}

border_color();
border_color2();
```

Alos you can see the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/GBGu8/

Comment: There's no JS in your fiddle : (.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same interval with some time margin for one of them

```
setTimeout(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        document.getElementById("filedrag").style.borderColor = "white";
    }, 1000);
}, 500);

setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("filedrag").style.borderColor = "black";
}, 1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GBGu8/1/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function border_color(){
 document.getElementById("filedrag").style.borderColor = "white";
 setTimeout(border_color2, 1000); 
}

function border_color2(){
 document.getElementById("filedrag").style.borderColor = "black"; 
setTimeout(border_color, 1000); 
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", border_color,false);
```

Comment: Did you try it on fiddle?

Comment: No, that is don't work, because white and black sets every 1000 mlsec, so it's always black.

Answer (score 0):

Just have the same interval alternate between black and white borders, no need for two intervals:

```
function border_color() {
  var style = document.getElementById("filedrag").style,
      color = style.borderColor;
  style.borderColor = color == 'white' ? 'black' : 'white';
  setTimeout(border_color, 1000);
}
border_color();
```